# braid and fattr problem on ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9, braid

i have a problems with running braid on ruby 1.9.2. The problem is with fattr gem

```
$ braid
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/fattr-2.1.0/lib/fattr.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in fattrs': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/fattr-2.1.0/lib/fattr.rb:90:in `instance_eval'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/fattr-2.1.0/lib/fattr.rb:90:in `call'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/fattr-2.1.0/lib/fattr.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in fattrs'
        from (eval):3:in `call'
        from (eval):3:in `arity!'
        from (eval):4:in `arity'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/parameter.rb:105:in `sanity_check!'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/parameter.rb:101:in `initialize'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/parameter.rb:53:in `block in create'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/parameter.rb:53:in `instance_eval'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/parameter.rb:53:in `create'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/program/class_methods.rb:193:in `option'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/program/class_methods.rb:92:in `set_default_options!'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/program/class_methods.rb:65:in `block in build'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/program/class_methods.rb:63:in `module_eval'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/program/class_methods.rb:63:in `build'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/factories.rb:16:in `run'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/main-4.2.0/lib/main/factories.rb:25:in `Main'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/braid-0.6.2/bin/braid:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/local/bin/braid:19:in `load'
        from /opt/local/bin/braid:19:in `<main>'
```

Do you know any solution for this problem?

Comment: The official fatter gem is now fixed for 1.9.2

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem on the main fattr branch/gem. Someone has patched it though the main branch hasn't pulled the changes yet. Try removing the fattr gem installed with braid and replacing it with this version https://github.com/kitop/fattr.

**Update**: The [main branch](https://github.com/ahoward/fattr) has now been updated for 1.9.2.